# How to prove a Linear Transformation is an identity mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Firstly, what's the definition of a identity map? I've thought of one but don't know if it's correct :" $P$ is a identity map if $P(x)=x$ for all $x$ on its domain."

Second, how to prove a projection transformation is an identity map on a specific domain.  More specifically,

> Let $P:  V \to V$ be a projection. Show that the restriction of $P$ to $\operatorname{range}(P)$ is the identity map on $\operatorname{range}(P)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of identity map is correct.

What did you try to solve the problem? Just start translating the data. Let $P:V\to V$ be a projection. What does that mean? It means that $\dots\dots$.

Now restrict $P$ to its range. So you have a map

\begin{align*}
P_{\big|\text{range}\,P}:\text{range}\, P&\to\text{range}\,P\\
v&\mapsto P(v).
\end{align*}

You want to show that $P_{\big|\text{range}\,P}$ is the identity map on $\text{range}\, P$, i.e, $$\forall v\in\text{range}\,P,P(v)=v.$$

Let's go. Let $v\in\text{range}\,P$. You want to compute $P(v)$. But wait a second: $v\in\text{range}\,P$. That's an important data. What does it mean? It means that $\dots\dots$.

Comment: P is projection means P(P(x))=P(x), right? So does that mean we need to show P(x) is in range(P) ? Is this obviously true or we still need further proof?

Comment: Yes that's what a projection is. Well keep translating the data: what is range(P)?

Comment: Range(P) = {P(x) ∈ V : x ∈ V } is this OK? Do we need more explanation?

Comment: Yes. I believe you can simply write $\text{range}\,P=\{P(x)\,:\,x\in V\}$. So, if you take $v\in\text{range}\,P=\{P(x)\,:\,x\in V\}$, what does that mean? That'll allow you to conclude that $P(v)=v$.